# How to stop AJAX form from refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I stop a form using AJAX from refreshing when using success and error? If I remove return false; after the end of the function, the error(Error validating CLid!) is displayed and the page refreshes, however if I leave it the ajax function submits and returns true with no refresh. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&company=' + phone + '&length=' + length + '$time=' + time + '&question' + question;

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "contact_process.php",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function() {  
       $('#search_contact').html("You're request for more information was submitted."); 
    },
    error: function() {
      $('#search_contact').html('Error validating CLid!');          
    } 
}); 


return false;

});
```

Comment: How do you handle the event that triggers the ajax request?

Comment: Did you know about http://api.jquery.com/serialize/? What happened here `length + '$time='`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that the page refreshes when doing your ajax-call. What's the js-code after the code you supplied? Are there any redirects or something? How are you calling the ajax-function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are triggering this ajax request through an event on a form submission or link click or something.

If you are triggering the request from a link, ie:

`<a href="contact_process.php" id="contactTrigger">Click me</a>`

When you bind the event you need to call event.preventDefault(); on the event passed to the event handler to prevent the default behavior, ie:

```
$('#contactTrigger').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   //do your ajax stuff here.
});
```